# Retrieving Hidden column using getCell in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, field, hidden

I have a **Hidden** column **invoiceid** defined in my JQGrid as below

```
{name:'invoiceid',index:'invoiceid',width:60,align:'center',hidden:true,editable:true,editrules: {edithidden:true}}
```

When I try retrieving this value using the below code

```
 var gr = jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
 var invoiceId = jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('getCell',gr,'invoiceid');
```

the value invoiceId is returned as **null**, why is it not retrieving the value of the hidden field ?

Comment: My bad :(, this seems to be working, there is no issue with the above code, in my grid the hidden col was not getting populated with proper values, it was null, so when i was trying to retrieve its value, it was showing up as null.

So please consider this query closed.

Thanks,
Deepna

Comment: You can delete the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Add `edittype:'text'` to your ColModel:

```
{name:'invoiceid', index:'invoiceid', width:60, align:'center', hidden:true, edittype:'text', editable:true, editrules: {edithidden:true}}
```

Comment: A little bit more description about what the error is and what the soultion does would be nice.